# awk pattern matching with if

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to multiply field $2 either by .75 or .1

I have this data:

```
Disputed,279
Processed,12112
Uncollected NSF,4732
Declined,14
Invalid / Closed Account,3022
```

Awk statement:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; FS=OFS=","; OFMT="%.2f"; }

{
        if ($1  "/Disputed|Uncollected|Invalid/")
                $3 = $2 * .75
        else 
                if ($1 ~  "/Processed|Declined/")
                $3 = $2 * 0.10
        print
}
```

Expected output:

```
Disputed,279,209.25
Processed,12112,1211.2
Uncollected NSF,4732,3549
Declined,14,1.4
Invalid / Closed Account,3022,2266.5
```

Current results:

```
Disputed,279,209.25
Processed,12112,9084
Uncollected NSF,4732,3549
Declined,14,10.5
Invalid / Closed Account,3022,2266.5
```

These are multiplied by .75: Disputed, Uncollected NSF and Invalid / Closed Account

These are multiplied by .1: Processed and Declined

what's causing all records to be multiplied by .75?

edit: this is my working solution...

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
     FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
     FS=OFS=","
     OFMT="%.2f"
     print "status","acct type","count","amount"
}

NF>1 {
     $4=$3 * ($1 ~ /Processed|Declined/ ? 0.10 : 0.75 )
     print
     trans+=$3
     fee+=$4
}

END {
     printf "------------\n"
     print "# of transactions: " trans
     print "processing fee: " fee
}
```

Yes, there's four fields. $2 is a hidden special field!

```
status,acct type,count,amount
Processed,Savings,502,50.2
Uncollected NSF,Checking,4299,3224.25
Disputed,Checking,263,197.25
Processed,Checking,11610,1161
Uncollected NSF,Savings,433,324.75
Declined,Checking,14,1.4
Invalid / Closed Account,Checking,2868,2151
Disputed,Savings,16,12
Invalid / Closed Account,Savings,154,115.5
------------
# of transactions: 20159
processing fee: 7237.35
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you have some pattern other than Disputed, Uncollected, Invalid, Processed, Declined?  You don't have a final `else` clause, so you don't add `$3` and you just print the input data.  But that's a logic issue wholly separate from the behaviour you're seeing, which has been addressed by the answers.

Comment: Well I really should have the three .75 values be it and all others multiplied at .10. I'm open to improvements!

Comment: OK; so drop the second `if` and have the `else` simply multiply by 0.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to write your code in awk would be with a ternary expression, e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, $2 * ($1 ~ /Processed|Declined/ ? 0.10 : 0.75)}' file
Disputed,279,209.25
Processed,12112,1211.2
Uncollected NSF,4732,3549
Declined,14,1.4
Invalid / Closed Account,3022,2266.5
```

Note that regexp constants are delimited by `/` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp) but awk can construct dynamic regexps from variables and/or string constants (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) so when you wrote:

```
"/Processed|Declined/"
```

in a context appropriate for a dynamic regexp (`$1 ~ <regexp>`), awk constructed a regexp from it as:

```
`/Processed` OR `Declined/`
```

(note the literal `/` chars as part of the regexp terms) instead of what you wanted:

```
`Processed` OR `Declined`
```

You can see that effect here:

```
$ echo 'abc' | awk '$0 ~ /b|x/'
abc
$ echo 'abc' | awk '$0 ~ "/b|x/"'
$ echo 'a/bc' | awk '$0 ~ "/b|x/"'
a/bc
```

Now, see if you can figure this out:

```
$ echo 'abc' | awk '$0 ~ "/b|x/"'
$ echo 'abc' | awk '"/b|x/"'
abc
```

i.e. why the first one prints nothing but the second one prints the input.

Comment: The answer to the question at the end of my answer is that `awk '$0 ~ "/b|x/"'` is testing if `$0` matches the regexp generated from the string `"/b|x/"` and if so it will print the record, but `awk '"/b|x/"'` is testing the VALUE of the string `"/b|x/"` and so will print the current record if that string is not null or zero, which it isn't, regardless of the value of `$0`. In that second case awk doesn't convert the string `"/b|x/"` to a regexp because it doesn't know for sure that you want it to as the context it appears in is not always a regexp context.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are missing a matching operator `~`. This statement:

```
 if ($1  "/Disputed|Uncollected|Invalid/")
```

always evaluates to true because it checks whether the concatenation of `$1` with `"/Disputed|Uncollected|Invalid/"` is not empty — and it isn't.

Try instead:

```
if ($1 ~ /Disputed|Uncollected|Invalid/)
```

**Examples**

You can see this behavior using following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) one-liners:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("" "a") { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
true
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("" "") { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
false
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("") { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
false
$ awk 'BEGIN { if (RS FS "a") { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
true
$ awk 'BEGIN { if (variable) { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
false
$ awk 'BEGIN { var="0"; if (var) { print "true" } else { print "false" }}'
true
```

Comment: With the ~, I'll have to have exactly the field $1 names. So that means Invalid / Closed Account will need to be in the awk statement instead of just `Invalid`.

Comment: `~` will do partial matching, it adds `.*` to the beginning and end of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

As the other poster said, you left out the `~` operator before the first regular expression.

Also, don't include slashes at the start and end of your regular expressions.  Either enclose your regular expressions in slashes (as in Perl/Ruby/JavaScript) or in quotes - not both.

```
if ($1 ~ "Disputed|Uncollected|Invalid")
    $3 = $2 * .75
else
    if ($1 ~  "Processed|Declined")
        $3 = $2 * 0.10
print
```

Comment: I think the forward slash can be used: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Patterns

Comment: Duly noted - edited to reflect this.  (Sorry, haven't done anything serious in awk for a while.)

Comment: Get rid of `Also, don't include slashes at the start and end of your regular expressions. Either enclose your regular expressions in slashes (as in Perl/Ruby/JavaScript) or in quotes - not both.` as the first sentence is 100% wrong and the second one makes it sound like the 2 delimiters are equivalent when they aren't. This is a regexp so use regexp delimiters `/`, don't force awk to construct a regexp from your text surrounded by string delimiters.